# PowerShell: Creating a Custom Exception

Tags: .net, powershell

Here is my code:

```
Function Foo {
    If (1 -Eq 2) {
        # Do stuff
    }
    Else {
        # Throw custom exception
    }
}

Try {
    Foo

    Write-Host "Success"
}
Catch {
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.InnerException.Message

    Write-Host "Failure"

    # Do stuff with the error message
}
```

I'd like to replace `# Throw custom exception` with code that will cause the `Catch` to fire. How can I do that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Not sure I really get your question, but it seems like all you want to do is to:

```
throw "message for the exception"
```

Comment: I was using `$ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.InnerException.Message` because I assumed that would work with `Throw`. It turns out it should be `$_.Exception.Message` in this case. Thanks!