# Creating and throwing new exception

Tags: powershell

How I can create and throw a new exception in PowerShell?

I want to do different things for a specific error.

Comment: Are you looking to throw a custom exception? Does [this][1] help?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703180/powershell-creating-a-custom-exception

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182666/powershell-2-0-try-catch-how-to-access-the-exception

Comment: You might be interested in https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-logging/

Answer (score 224):

To call a specific exception such as FileNotFoundException use this format

```
if (-not (Test-Path $file)) 
{
    throw [System.IO.FileNotFoundException] "$file not found."
}
```

To throw a general exception use the throw command followed by a string.

```
throw "Error trying to do a task"
```

When used inside a catch, you can provide additional information about what triggered the error

Comment: In C++, it is discouraged to throw strings, since they are not in the exception hierarchy.  It just works, as in Powershell, but maybe they are not the best way to go?

Comment: If you are using try..catches in your script and you have multiple catch statements calling out specific exceptions then, of course, you would want to specify the exception type. I'm not certain why a reference is made to C++. In Powershell scripting, a throw statement is most usually intended to exit the script with a descriptive message. I'm not looking to spark a debate, but Powershell and C++ are extremely different animals. Applying C++ or C# best practices to Powershell should be tempered, since scripting is more closely associated with functional programming.

Answer (score 13):

You can throw your own custom errors by extending the Exception class.

```
class CustomException : Exception {
    [string] $additionalData

    CustomException($Message, $additionalData) : base($Message) {
        $this.additionalData = $additionalData
    }
}

try {
    throw [CustomException]::new('Error message', 'Extra data')
} catch [CustomException] {
    # NOTE: To access your custom exception you must use $_.Exception
    Write-Output $_.Exception.additionalData

    # This will produce the error message: Didn't catch it the second time
    throw [CustomException]::new("Didn't catch it the second time", 'Extra data')
}
```

Comment: This is one off from the OP, but holy cow this is the exact answer I was looking for. Thank you.