# How do I actually generate an error using $PSCmdlet.WriteError in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet, write-error

I've been reading up on generating error messages in PowerShell and stumbled across this example...

```
$Exception = [Exception]::new("error message")
$ErrorRecord = [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]::new(
    $Exception,
    "errorID",
    [System.Management.Automation.ErrorCategory]::NotSpecified,
    $TargetObject # usually the object that triggered the error, if possible
)
$PSCmdlet.WriteError($ErrorRecord)
```

However, this isn't a working example. I can't start experimenting with it, since I have no idea what would make the example tick to begin with.

```
InvalidOperation: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

I do know I could use `Write-Error` instead to generate a non-terminating error. But I really don't like the error message to echo the command I used to generate the error message.

Comment: Santiago's answer solves your primary problem, but note that even a non-terminating error written with `$PSCmdlet.WriteError()` results in an error message that ix prefixed with the name of the error-emitting command.

Comment: Powershell script have a number of different output type (see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/types-of-cmdlet-output?view=powershell-7.3_) Write-Error writes to the error output, it doesn't trigger the exception.  To throw exception see following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981208/creating-and-throwing-new-exception

Comment: @jdweng, the question is explicitly about writing a _non-terminating_ error (an error written to PowerShell's error output stream), which both `Write-Error` and `$PSCmdlet.WriteError()` do.

Comment: @mklement0 : The OP said "I have no idea what would make the example tick to begin with"

Comment: @jdweng, to quote the Society for [Non Sequiturs](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/non%20sequitur): We may not make sense, but we sure love bananas.

Comment: @jdweng, I clarified the question somewhat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks good, the only problem is that [`$PSCmdlet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#pscmdlet) is only available for you in the context of an [advanced function or script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-7.3):

```bash
function Testing {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param($TargetObject)

    $Exception = [Exception]::new('error message')
    $ErrorRecord = [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]::new(
        $Exception,
        'errorID',
        [System.Management.Automation.ErrorCategory]::NotSpecified,
        $TargetObject) # usually the object that triggered the error, if possible

    $PSCmdlet.WriteError($ErrorRecord)
}

Testing foo!
```

---

Following up on comments, again, in the context of a script block (be it an `Invoke-Command` or `Start-Job` or any other script block) it would need to be an advanced one, so it would need to have a `[cmdletbinding()]` or `[Parameter(...)]` decoration for that to happen:

```
Start-Job {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param($TargetObject)

    $Exception = [Exception]::new('error message')
    $ErrorRecord = [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]::new(
        $Exception,
        'errorID',
        [System.Management.Automation.ErrorCategory]::NotSpecified,
        $TargetObject) # usually the object that triggered the error, if possible

    $PSCmdlet.WriteError($ErrorRecord)
} -ArgumentList foo! | Receive-Job -AutoRemoveJob -Wait

$Error[0].TargetObject # foo!
```

Comment: Ah, that's what throw me of. Since the $PSCmdlet variable and the associated methods are accessible from the shell, I assumed I could use them directly from the prompt.

Comment: But I have issues running it as a scriptblock. Both `Invoke-Command {<the example>}` and `Start-Job {<the example>}` will fail in the same way...