# check for ping and then uptime?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

The below checks for uptime. One condition I did not tink of (except for now) is if the server can be pinged BUT CANNOT GET THE UPTIME - I need the below script to error out if that is the case. I cannot think of how to do this - any ideas?

CODE:

```
#clear
$Computers = Get-Content "E:\DATA\PS_Jobs\Patching_Uptime\Saturday_Servers.txt"

Foreach($computer in $Computers) 
{

    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Quiet)
    {

    $LastBoot = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -computername $computer).LastBootUpTime
    $sysuptime = (Get-Date) – [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeconverter]::ToDateTime($LastBoot)

    $days = $sysuptime.Days
    $DaystoHours = ($sysuptime.Days)*24
    $hours = $sysuptime.hours
    $TotalHours = $DaystoHours + $hours

        if($TotalHours -gt '12')
        {
            Write-EventLog -LogName WinLondonUptime -Source Uptime -EntryType Error -EventId 5 -Message "$computer - FAILED - Servers Uptime is GREATER then 12 hours or not contactable - Uptime is $days Days and $hours Hours - This is the Saturday patching run"
        }
        else
        {
            Write-EventLog -LogName WinLondonUptime -Source Uptime -EntryType Information -EventId 4 -Message "$computer - SUCCESS - Servers uptime is less than 12 hours - Uptime is $days Days and $hours Hours - This is the Saturday patching run"
        }
    }
    else
        {
            Write-EventLog -LogName WinLondonUptime -Source Uptime -EntryType Error -EventId 5 -Message "$computer - FAILED - Server is not contactable - This is the Saturday patching run"
        }
}
```

Comment: While I'm not sure whether this is offtopic on SO, I think you have a better chance of getting answers on Powershell on [su].

Comment: You can calculate the up-time be Getting the longest running process or querying the system event log to get Event ID 6005.

Comment: think I asked this slightly incorrectly - a lot of you are thinking I want to get UPTIME - it is incorrect - the above code does get the uptime. I was specifically asking when UPTIME is not available for a specific server I want it to error out....even if the server is up and pinging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encapsulate your code in a try/catch and use a timespan object. Something like this (not tested, but it gives you the idea):

```
    try
    {
        Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction Stop

        $wmi = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -computer $computer
        $time = $wmi.ConvertToDateTime($wmi.Lastbootuptime) 
        [TimeSpan] $uptime = New-TimeSpan $time $(get-date)

        if ($uptime.Hours -gt 12)
        {
            Write-EventLog -LogName WinLondonUptime -Source Uptime -EntryType Error -EventId 5 -Message "$computer - FAILED - Servers Uptime is GREATER then 12 hours or not contactable - Uptime is $days Days and $hours Hours - This is the Saturday patching run"
        }
        else
        {
            Write-EventLog -LogName WinLondonUptime -Source Uptime -EntryType Information -EventId 4 -Message "$computer - SUCCESS - Servers uptime is less than 12 hours - Uptime is $($uptime.Days) Days and $($uptime.Hours) Hours - This is the Saturday patching run"
        }
    }

    catch [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreferenceStopException]
    {
        Write-EventLog -LogName WinLondonUptime -Source Uptime -EntryType Error -EventId 5 -Message "$computer - FAILED - Server is not contactable - This is the Saturday patching run"
    }
```

Comment: thanks David - this helped me and think you knew what I was asking!

Answer (score 1):

You can get also get a computer's last bootup time using WMI:

```
$wmi = [WMI] ""
$operatingSystem = get-wmiobject Win32_OperatingSystem -computername "."
$wmi.ConvertToDateTime($operatingSystem.LastBootUpTime)
```

Bill

Comment: thanks for that but think I asked this slightly incorrectly - a lot of you are thinking I want to get UPTIME - it is incorrect - the above code does get the uptime. I was specifically asking when UPTIME is not available for a specific server I want it to error out....even if the server is up and pinging.

Answer (score 1):

This person sort of has the same problem with [WMI not having a timeout feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dmuscett/archive/2009/05/27/get_2d00_wmicustom.aspx). What you might try is creating a job to query WMI and get the LBUT. Then just set a timer on the job. But if you want to just do some error handling you should use `try{}` and `catch{}` blocks.

```
try{
    $lbut = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -computername $computer).LastBootUpTime
}
catch{
    "FAILED"
    continue
}
```

[You might want to look at using CIM instead of WMI](http://mcpmag.com/Articles/List/Prof-Powershell.aspx).

Comment: I will try this out - looks similar to what David gave with the try catch method.

Answer (score 0):

*Erroring Out* is typically defined as returning a non zero exit code, this can be done by

```
Exit 1
```

or

```
Exit -1
```

Or whatever number you prefer.

You can also throw exceptions as well, if you want to send a specific error message and a really nasty error, there's an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703180/powershell-creating-a-custom-exception).

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this from here at the moment but perhaps try nesting another if statement to enumerate the success or failure of the call to WMI?

```
if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Quiet)
    {

    if((Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -computername $computer).LastBootUpTime){

        $LastBoot = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -computername $computer).LastBootUpTime
        $sysuptime = (Get-Date) – [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeconverter]::ToDateTime($LastBoot)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is as follows. I'm pinging the hostname and getting the boot time if it does not get the error.

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("hostname").ipaddresstostring
if($? -eq $true){
   Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | select lastbootuptime
}
```