# Powershell throw exceptions with data

Tags: powershell, exception, throw

How to use 'throw' direction in PowerShell to throw an exception with custom data object?
Say, could it do this?:

```
throw 'foo', $myData
```

then the data can be used in 'catch' logic:

```
catch {
    if ($_.exception.some_property -eq 'foo') {
        $data = $_.exception.some_field_to_get_data
        # dealing with data
    }
}
```

edited:
My intention is to know is there a brief and cool syntax to throw an exception (without explicitly creating my own type) with a name that I can decide by its name and deal with its data in the 'catch' blocks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerShell: Creating a Custom Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703180/powershell-creating-a-custom-exception)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `throw` any kind of `System.Exception` instance (here using a [`XamlException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd292274(v=vs.110).aspx) as an example):

```
try {
    $Exception = New-Object System.Xaml.XamlException -ArgumentList ("Bad XAML!", $null, 10, 2)
    throw $Exception
}
catch{
    if($_.Exception.LineNumber -eq 10){
        Write-Host "Error on line 10, position $($_.Exception.LinePosition)"
    }
}
```

---

If you're running version 5.0 or newer of PowerShell, you can use the new PowerShell Classes feature to define custom Exception types:

```
class MyException : System.Exception
{
    [string]$AnotherMessage
    [int]$SomeNumber

    MyException($Message,$AnotherMessage,$SomeNumber) : base($Message){
        $this.AnotherMessage = $AnotherMessage
        $this.SomeNumber     = $SomeNumber
    }
}

try{
    throw [MyException]::new('Fail!','Something terrible happened',135)
}
catch [MyException] {
    $e = $_.Exception
    if($e.AnotherMessage -eq 'Something terrible happened'){
        Write-Warning "$($e.SomeNumber) terrible things happened"
    }
}
```

Comment: `("Bad XAML!", $null, 10, 2)` welp, how do you find how to pass something like this?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Either look at the constructor documentation on MSDN (linked above), or look at the overload definitions: `[System.Xaml.XamlException]::new` (v 5.0+) or `[System.Xaml.XamlException].GetConstructors()|%{'new {0}({1})'-f$_.DeclaringType,(($_.GetParameters()|%{'{0} {1}'-f$_.ParameterType.FullName,$_.Name})-join', ')}` (older versions)

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted but it is a workaround for my problem. Really inspiring. Thanks to all!

Comment: @DaveWu Added an example of extending the `System.Exception` class in PS 5.0, in earlier versions you could do this with external code written in C# or VB.NET for example